# разделить (split()) текст по двум абзацам "\n\n" Android?

Tags: android

у меня в strings.xml есть текст который содержит 2 параграфа ("\n\n")  как сделать split по этим параметрам? такое почему-то не работает  `String.split("\n\n")` `String.split("\\n\\n")`

[image]

на экране отображается нормально

[image]

Comment: `\r\n` попробуйте

Answer (score 0):

val content = resources.getString(R.string.test).split("\n \n ")
strings.xml

first
        \n
        \n
        second
надо добавить пробел \n.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61931295/how-to-split-text-by-n-n-android